# Resize UITextView Parent UIView When Adding To UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a UIView that contains a number of UITextViews that resize to fit the text, the last text view is connected to the base of the parent UIView via Autolayout. The UIView then gets dynamically added to the UIScrollView using the following

```
 for (UIView *subview in self.scrollViewContent.subviews) {
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }

    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;

    NSLog(@"%f",self.txtViewEndOfFAQ.frame.size.height);

    [self.viewFAQ setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, (self.txtViewEndOfFAQ.frame.origin.y + self.txtViewEndOfFAQ.frame.size.height))];


    [self.scrollViewContent addSubview:self.viewFAQ];
    [self.scrollViewContent setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.viewFAQ.frame.size.width,   self.viewFAQ.frame.size.height)];


    [self addUnderline:self.imageViewTitle4];

    [self showMenu:nil];
```

Now the issue is that when its loaded it doesn't give me the correct height. With narrower devices the textviews height increases to fit the text and this doesn't seem to be taken into account.

Comment: why not simply use UITableView. It would be much easier

Comment: I agree with @rv7284 . Use table view with automatic row height calculations. It should be simple and iOS will automatically manage these things for you.

Comment: Where are you running this code? Is it in viewDidLoad?

Comment: No it is later on on press of a UIButton, I think I am going to try and switch to a UITableView and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a height constraint programmatically so long as it doesn't create a conflict with your existing constraints. With NSLayoutConstraint that would be something like:

```
NSLayoutConstraint *heightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint
                       constraintWithItem:self.viewFAQ
                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                       relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                       toItem:self.txtViewEndOfFAQ
                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                       multiplier:1.0
                       constant:0];

[self addConstraints: heightConstraint];
```

Using NSLayoutAnchor:

```
[self.viewFAQ.heightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.txtViewEndOfFAQ.heightAnchor].active = YES;
```